# ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

Tags: sql, oracle, playframework

> alter table bu_consultas drop constraint if exists fk_b_cnslts_cdg_sr_d;

Error SQL: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].

Comment: Please read the documentation, too - it will take one minute to find out what is wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `IF EXISTS` clause in [the `ALTER TABLE` command for Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001). If the constraint doesn't exist the command will fail, but no harm done.